# Sending multiple images over socket

Tags: java, sockets

what im trying to do:

```
client connects to server
server sends READY
client takes screenshot and sends it
server processes image

server sends READY
client takes screenshot and sends it
server processes image
...
```

i have a working client and server:

```
Client() {

    try {
        socket = new Socket(host, 4444);
        in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        int ix = 0;
        while (true) {
            switch (in.readInt()) {
            case Var.READY:
                image = new Robot().createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));
                ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayO = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                ImageIO.write(image,"PNG",byteArrayO);
                byte [] byteArray = byteArrayO.toByteArray();
                out.writeInt(byteArray.length);
                out.write(byteArray);
                System.out.println("send screen " + ix++);
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.err.println("Don't know about host");
        System.exit(1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection " + e.getMessage());
        System.exit(1);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

Server:

```
 public class ServerWorker implements Runnable {

private Socket socket = null;

DataInputStream in = null;
DataOutputStream out = null;

ServerWorker() {

}

synchronized void setSocket(Socket socket) {
    this.socket = socket;
    try {
        in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    notify();
}

public synchronized void run() {
    int ix = 0;
    try {
        while (true) {
            out.writeInt(Var.READY);
            int nbrToRead = in.readInt();
            byte[] byteArray = new byte[nbrToRead];
            int nbrRd = 0;
            int nbrLeftToRead = nbrToRead;
            while(nbrLeftToRead > 0){ 
                int rd =in.read(byteArray, nbrRd, nbrLeftToRead);
                if(rd < 0)
                    break;
                nbrRd += rd; // accumulate bytes read
                nbrLeftToRead -= rd;
            }
            //Converting the image
            ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayI = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray);
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(byteArrayI);
            System.out.println("received screen " + ix++);
            //image.flush();
            File of = new File("RecvdImg" + ix + ".jpg");
            ImageIO.write(image, "PNG" ,of);
            System.out.println("Sleeping 1..");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
}
}
```

So whats the question you might ask?
Well, am i doing it right?
Activity monitor tells me the client side takes about 40% of cpu constantly, that cant be good.

Just wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction to making the code more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Client could detect if the image has changed, and if it hasn't it could send to the server a flag indicating to reuse the previous image received. Or you can "diff" the image and send only the changed areas to the server, which will recompose the image. That reduces bandwidth usage and perhaps also CPU usage.

Also, the client should sleep a while in the receiving endless loop, after the `switch`.

Comment: Thanks i'll implement the change detection! for the sleeping, is it necessary as in.readInt() blocks until it receives something right?

Comment: Regarding the sleep, the client should be blocked in `in.readInt()` most of the time anyway.

Comment: But I'm worried if readInt consumes CPU cycles itself... Anyway I think the sleep improves performance because after sending an image, the client can "take a break" before waiting again for the request.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should avoid using infinit-loops like

```
while (true)
```

Loops like

```
while(!connectionAborted)
```

are better in such situations.

Also you should take a look at
[Socket.setSoTimeout()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setSoTimeout%28int%29)

SoTimeout cancels the reading-process of i.e. `in.readInt()` after an specific amount of time, depending on your parameter.
The result is that at this line a `SocketTimeoutException` is thrown, but your code is not stuck at this codeline and can react on i.e. different user inputs.