# Android ImageView not showing received images from socket connection

Tags: android, sockets, imageview

I am trying to show two consecutive images in an Android app, which are received through a socket (from a C program using sendfile). The sender code seems to work ok, and I am having issues with the Android code side.

Part of the code in the Android app is the following:

```
public class DisplayNewActivity extends Activity {
    ...
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ....
        mHandler = new Handler() {
           @Override
           public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
               Drawable d2;
               d2 = (Drawable)msg.obj;
               imageSock.setImageDrawable(d2); // to set the arrived image in the imageshow object
           }
        };
        ...
        cThread = new Thread(new ClientThread());
        rThread = new Thread(new RcvThread());
        cThread.start();
    }

    public class ClientThread implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
           // thread used for socket connection.
           ...
           rThread.start(); // once the connection has been established
           ...
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("HandlerLeak")
    public class RcvThread implements Runnable {
         public void run() {
            while (connected) {
               try {
                  InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
                  Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(inputStream, null);
                  Message msg = new Message();
                  msg.obj = d;
                  mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
               } catch (Exception e) {
                  Log.e("SocketConnectionv02Activity", "C: ErrorRCVD", e);
               }
            }
         }
    }
 }
```

The problem I am facing is that after the first image received by the Android app is shown correctly, then the next one received (which is correctly received) is not shown and leaves the imageview object showing a white space.

Any suggestion/idea to solve this issue?.

Thanks in advance for any help you could provide.

EDIT:

```
public class DisplayNewActivity extends Activity {
    ...
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ....
        mHandler = new Handler() {
           @Override
           public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
               Bitmap d2;
               d2 = (Bitmap)msg.obj;
               imageSock.setImageBitmap(d2); // to set the arrived image in the imageshow object
           }
        };
        ...
        cThread = new Thread(new ClientThread());
        rThread = new Thread(new RcvThread());
        cThread.start();
    }

    public class ClientThread implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
           // thread used for socket connection.
           ...
           rThread.start(); // once the connection has been established
           ...
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("HandlerLeak")
    public class RcvThread implements Runnable {
         public void run() {
            while (connected) {
               try {
                  DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                  Bitmap d = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
                  Message msg = new Message();
                  msg.obj = d;
                  mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
               } catch (Exception e) {
                  Log.e("SocketConnectionv02Activity", "C: ErrorRCVD", e);
               }
            }
         }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the issue you are having is in decoding the data into a proper image after receiving it.

I might recommend not using `Drawable.createFromStream()` and instead using `BitmapFactory.decodeStream()` or manually downloading the data into a `byte[]` first and using `BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray()`.  Sometimes the latter is useful if the former can't sufficiently keep up with the decoder as the data is received.

The method you are currently using actually ends up calling `BitmapFactory.descodeResourceStream()`, which is used to read image data out of the local res/ package and not so much from a remote socket.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. From the code I posted I changed the lines "InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream(); Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(inputStream, null);" to "DataInputStream d = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());" and "Drawable d2; d2 = (Drawable)msg.obj; imageSock.setImageDrawable(d2);" to "DataInputStream d2; d2 = (DataInputStream)msg.obj; imageSock.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(d2));" and it does not work at all. In fact the app does not answer anymore. Am I setting it wrong?

Comment: Do you think that getting the information the way this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11926421/sending-multiple-images-over-socket#comment15883123_11926455 does would help me for my purpose?

Comment: I would have still kept the decoding on the background thread and just passed back the `Bitmap` instead of a `Drawable`.  Changing the code to call `decodeStream()` on the main thread is probably now causing an AND because that operation takes a long time.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I have changed the code to the one shown the edited part of the original question, but the result is basically the same than the one from the original post. Also, I am using Gingerbread, would that affect the code? If you have any further idea, I would really appreciate it.